# execution order when running a javascript inside ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am noob to ASP.net.
I was trying to add a confirmation popup to webpage.
I used the following code :
(which is a variant from this one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8173/A-Simple-ASP-NET-Server-Control-Message-Box-Confir )

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;

namespace BunnyBear
{

    [DefaultProperty("Text"),
        ToolboxData("<{0}:msgBox runat=server></{0}:msgBox>")]
    public class msgBox : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl
    {
        //private string msg;
        private string content;

        [Bindable(true),
            Category("Appearance"),
            DefaultValue("")]

  public  void confirm2(string msg)
        {
            string sMsg = msg.Replace("\n", "\\n");
            sMsg = msg.Replace("\"", "'");

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();



            sb.Append(@"<script language='javascript'>");

            sb.Append(@" if(confirm( """ + sMsg + @""" ))");
            sb.Append(@" { }");

            sb.Append(@" else { ");
            sb.Append( "document.forms[0].submit(); }");


            sb.Append(@"</script>");

            content = sb.ToString();
        }
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            output.Write(this.content);
        }
    }
}
```

I try it from a test class as follows :

```
     //event triggered when clicking a button
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
            {
                msgBox1.confirm2("are you sure?");


               MoreCode();
            }
```

I was expecting that when I click on the button, the confirmation popup pops and asks if I want to confirm:

- if I click "no" : postback occurs so MoreCode() is not executed
- If I click "yes" : no javascript code is executed, so the execution goes on and MoreCode() is executed.

This is not what happens.
When I click the button with the step by step debugger, I can see that :

- it executes msgBox1.confirm2("are you sure?");
- it then executes MoreCode()
- and afterwards the popup pops

Could you pls explain me why this is executed in this order?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

MoreCode() is running on the server side, whereas the popup is on the client side. They are independent operations. If MoreCode *must* run after the button click, then you need to have a callback in your JavaScript, appending it after

```
sb.Append(@" if(confirm( """ + sMsg + @""" ))");
```

The callback would bind to a server call, and that server call would execute MoreCode.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using any AJAX, the order of operations is clear: all server-side code is run, then HTML is returned to the browser where the browser executes any necessary client-side code. Here is what happens, in order, starting from when your `Button2` is clicked:

1. `Button2_Click` server event is called. This event does everything it is asked to do: create a string that will be injected to the resulting HTML page, and then run `MoreCode()`. Control has not yet been returned to the browser--all this processing is handled on the server-side.
2. HTML for the resulting page is rendered, along with the string you injected, which includes the JavaScript you have written.
3. HTML is transferred to the browser and the HTML is executed. Your script triggers a JavaScript prompt, which is then displayed to the user using the text that was specified server-side.